# Accessing jquery object without "this"

Tags: jquery

I'm using this plugin:

http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Here's my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/DC5yT/1/

And I'm trying to use this (which works)

```
var logic = function( currentDateTime ){
  // 'this' is jquery object datetimepicker
  if( currentDateTime.getDay()==6 ){
    this.setOptions({
      minTime:'11:00'
    });
  }else
    this.setOptions({
      minTime:'8:00'
    });
};
jQuery('#datetimepicker_rantime').datetimepicker({
  onChangeDateTime:logic,
  onShow:logic
});
```

Except I'm using two calendars which affect eachother so I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
$("#end").setOptions({
      minTime:'8:00'
    });
```

But I get

> setOptions is not a function

How can I select one of my date pickers without having to use "this."?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: No, I did not. I ended up doing it a completely different way so that I reference each item by id instead of using this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the setOptions like this

```
$("#end").data("xdsoft_datetimepicker").setOptions({
    minTime:'8:00'
});
```

I have updated your fiddle to change the end max date once the start date/time it changed.

http://jsfiddle.net/DC5yT/3/

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just assign it as a variable?

```
var logic = function( currentDateTime ){
  // 'this' is jquery object datetimepicker
  if( currentDateTime.getDay()==6 ){
    this.setOptions({
      minTime:'11:00'
    });
  }else
    this.setOptions({
      minTime:'8:00'
    });
};
var dateTimePickerOne = jQuery('#datetimepicker_rantime').datetimepicker({
  onChangeDateTime:logic,
  onShow:logic
});
```

Then:

```
dateTimePickerOne.setOptions(...)
```

Comment: I tried this solution but without any luck: http://jsfiddle.net/DC5yT/1/ Am i doing something wrong?